# I have some list boxes floating elsewhere

Tags: html, vue.js

I have some list boxes and they are opening the list in different places from where they are. I tried to change the div locations already and tried to change the classes, but nothing works.

Correct behavior:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqdRc.png

Wrong behavior:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSXWQ.png

Is this my version vuetify
"vuetify": "^2.2.3",

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid class="pt-0 grid-list-xl">
    <app-section-loader :status="loader"></app-section-loader>
    <div class="app-card mt-5 px-3 py-3">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="box-dark lg mr-3 mt-2 text-primary d-none d-sm-flex">
          <bioIcon :size="28"></bioIcon>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-grow-1">
          <a @click="$router.back()">
            <i class="uil uil-arrow-left font-2x text-gray"></i>
          </a>
          <h3>
            {{ biodigester.name }}
            <span class="ml-2 fw-normal fs-12"
              >#{{ biodigester.serialNumber }}</span
            >
          </h3>
          <h4 class="fs-14 text-primary">{{ biodigester.model }}</h4>
        </div>
        <v-btn icon @click="setActive">
          <svg
            width="18"
            height="18"
            viewBox="0 0 18 18"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <path
              d="M0 14V16H6V14H0ZM0 2V4H10V2H0ZM10 18V16H18V14H10V12H8V18H10ZM4 6V8H0V10H4V12H6V6H4ZM18 10V8H8V10H18ZM12 6H14V4H18V2H14V0H12V6Z"
              fill="currentColor"
            />
          </svg>
        </v-btn>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div
      class="d-flex mt-10 app-card px-3 py-3 align-center justify-end flex-wrap"
    >
      <!--v-btn :disabled="!biodigester.serialNumber || !biodigester.name || !biodigester.model" color="primary" @click="save" class="mr-3"-->
      <v-btn color="primary" @click="save" class="mr-3">  
        <div   class="d-none d-sm-flex">Salvar Alterações</div>
        <div class="d-flex d-sm-none">Salvar</div>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn color="grey lighten-2" class="mr-3" @click="deleteItem">
        <!-- Excluir -->
        <div class="d-none d-sm-flex">Desvincular Biodigestor</div>
        <div class="d-flex d-sm-none">Desvincular</div>
      </v-btn>
      <!-- <v-btn color="grey lighten-2">
        <i class="uil uil-lock fs-20"></i>
      </v-btn> @change="save" guardado para o futuro-->
    </div>

    <div class="app-card mt-10 pa-3">
      <v-col class="col-6 col-md-4 page">
        <h5 class="text-primary text-uppercase mt-5 mb-3">
          Dados basicos
        </h5>

        <v-row flex-wrap>
          <v-col :disabled="!biodigester.name || !biodigester.setupDate" class="col-12 col-md-6">
            <template v-if="!biodigester.serialNumber">
              <v-label>Número de Série</v-label>
              <v-autocomplete
                :items="serialNumList"
                class="mt-3"
                dense
                v-model="biodId"
                outlined
                hide-details="auto"
              ></v-autocomplete>
            </template>
            <template v-else>
              <v-label>Número de Série</v-label>
              <v-autocomplete
                class="mt-3"
                :items="[biodigester.serialNumber]"
                dense
                v-model="biodigester.serialNumber"
                readonly
                outlined
                hide-details="auto"
              ></v-autocomplete>
            </template>
            <template v-if="!biodigester.companyId">
              <v-label>Cliente / Empresa</v-label>
              <v-autocomplete
                :items="companies"
                class="mt-3"
                v-model="biodigesterCompany"
                dense
                outlined
                hide-details="auto"
              ></v-autocomplete>
            </template>
            <template v-else>
              <v-label>Cliente / Empresa</v-label>
              <v-autocomplete
                :items="companies"
                class="mt-3"
                readonly
                v-model="biodigesterCompany"
                dense
                outlined
                hide-details="auto"
              ></v-autocomplete>
            </template>
            <template>
              <v-label>Status fabricação</v-label>
              <v-text-field
                class="mt-3"
                readonly
                v-model="fstatus"
                dense
                outlined
                hide-details="auto"
                ></v-text-field>
            </template>
            <template>
              <v-label>Status Entrega</v-label>
              <v-text-field
                class="mt-3"
                readonly
                v-model="estatus"
                dense
                outlined
                hide-details="auto"
                ></v-text-field>
            </template>            
          </v-col>
          <v-col class="col-12 col-md-6">
            <template>
              <v-label>Data ativação</v-label>
              <v-text-field
                class="mt-3"
                dense
                v-mask="'##/##/####'"
                v-model="biodigester.activeDate"
                outlined
                hide-details="auto"
              ></v-text-field>
            </template>
            <template>
              <v-label>Data de Fabricação / Previsão fábrica</v-label>
              <v-text-field
                class="mt-3"
                dense
                v-model="biodigester.manufacturingDate"
                v-mask="'##/##/####'"
                outlined
                hide-details="auto"
              ></v-text-field>
            </template>
            <template>
              <v-label>Data de Instalação / Previsão Instalação</v-label>
              <v-text-field
                class="mt-3"
                dense
                v-model="biodigester.installDate"
                v-mask="'##/##/####'"
                outlined
                hide-details="auto"
              ></v-text-field>
            </template>
            <template>
              <v-label>Data de Entrega </v-label>
              <v-text-field
                class="mt-3"
                dense
                v-model="biodigester.deliveryDate"
                v-mask="'##/##/####'"
                outlined
                hide-details="auto"
              ></v-text-field>
            </template>            
            
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-col>
      <v-col class="col-6 col-md-4 page">
        
        <h5 class="text-primary text-uppercase mt-5 mb-3">Dados do biodigestor</h5>

        <v-row flex-wrap align="end">
          <v-col :disabled="!biodigester.name || !biodigester.setupDate" class="col-12 col-md-6">
            <template>
              <v-label>Nome do Biodigestor</v-label>
              <v-text-field
                class="mt-3"
                dense
                v-model="biodigester.name"
                outlined
                hide-details="auto"
              ></v-text-field>
            </template>
            
            <template >
              <v-label>Perfil</v-label>
              <v-autocomplete
                :items="profile"
                class="mt-3"
                v-model="biodigester.profile"
                dense
                outlined
                hide-details="auto"
              ></v-autocomplete>              
            </template>
            <template>
              <v-label>Apalis instalada</v-label>
              <v-autocomplete
                :items="apalis"
                class="mt-3"
                v-model="biodigester.apalis"
                dense
                outlined
                hide-details="auto"
              ></v-autocomplete>
            </template>
            <template>
              <v-label>Capacidade</v-label>
              <v-autocomplete
                :items="nominalCapacity"
                class="mt-3"
                v-model="biodigester.nominalCapacity"
                dense
                outlined
                hide-details="auto"
              ></v-autocomplete>
            </template>
          </v-col>
          <v-col class="col-12 col-md-6">
            <template>
              <v-label>Fornecedor</v-label>
              <v-text-field
                class="mt-3"
                dense
                v-model="biodigester.fornecedor"
                outlined
                hide-details="auto"
              ></v-text-field>
            </template>             
            <template>
              <v-label>Centro de Custo</v-label>
              <v-text-field
                class="mt-3"
                dense
                v-model="biodigester.ccusto"
                outlined
                hide-details="auto"
              ></v-text-field>
            </template>                         
          </v-col>
        </v-row>

        <h5 class="text-primary text-uppercase mt-5 mb-3">Outros dados</h5>
        <v-row flex-wrap>
          <v-col class="col-12 col-sm-6 py-0">
            <template>
              <v-label>Data de Contrato</v-label>
              <v-text-field
                class="mt-3"
                dense
                readonly
                v-model="biodigester.contratDate"
                v-mask="'##/##/####'"
                outlined
                hide-details="auto"
              ></v-text-field>
            </template>          
          </v-col>
          <v-col class="col-12 col-sm-6 py-0">
            <template>
              <v-label>Data real de instalação</v-label>
              <v-text-field
                class="mt-3"
                dense
                readonly
                v-model="biodigester.realinstallDate"
                v-mask="'##/##/####'"
                outlined
                hide-details="auto"
              ></v-text-field>
            </template>
          </v-col>

          <v-col class="col-12 col-sm-6 py-0">
            <v-label>CEP</v-label>
            <v-text-field
              class="mt-3"
              dense
              @change="getCep(biodigester.zip)"
              v-mask="'#####-###'"
              v-model="biodigester.zip"
              outlined
              hide-details="auto"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
          <v-col class="col-12 col-sm-6 py-0">
            <v-label>Cidade</v-label>
            <v-text-field
              class="mt-3"
              dense
              outlined
              v-model="biodigester.city"
              hide-details="auto"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
          <v-col class="col-12 col-sm-6 py-0">
            <v-label>Logradouro</v-label>
            <v-text-field
              class="mt-3"
              dense
              v-model="biodigester.publicPlace"
              outlined
              hide-details="auto"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
          <v-col class="col-12 col-sm-6 py-0">
            <v-label>Estado</v-label>
            <v-text-field
              class="mt-3"
              dense
              :maxlength="2"
              @input="upper($event)"
              v-model="biodigester.state"
              outlined
              hide-details="auto"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
          <v-col class="col-12 col-sm-6 py-0">
            <v-label>Número</v-label>
            <v-text-field
              class="mt-3"
              dense
              v-model="biodigester.number"
              outlined
              hide-details="auto"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
          <v-col class="col-12 col-sm-6 py-0">
            <v-label>Complemento</v-label>
            <v-text-field
              class="mt-3"
              dense
              v-model="biodigester.complement"
              outlined
              hide-details="auto"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
          <v-col class="col-12 col-sm-6 py-0">
            <v-label>Geolocalização</v-label>
            <v-text-field
              class="mt-3"
              dense
              v-model="biodigester.geolocation"
              outlined
              hide-details="auto"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-col>
    
    
    
    </div>


    <delete-confirmation-dialog
      ref="deleteConfirmationDialog"
      heading="Excluir item"
      message="Tem certeza que deseja excluir este item?"
      @onConfirm="onDelete"
    >
    </delete-confirmation-dialog>
    <config-sidebar ref="configSidebar"></config-sidebar>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Code below is the complete excerpt of what is happening to me, are a set of edit box and list box that renders some data from a database, I have no problems getting the data but only in this part where the content is appearing at the beginning of the page

I have some list boxes and they are opening the list in different places from where they are. I tried to change the div locations already and tried to change the classes, but nothing works.

This is link to [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)! but i dont replay the problem i thing because of version you have ideia !

Comment: Can you create a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com) (or similar) reproducing the issue?

Comment: I tried but it's a system with many dependencies and link its too long

Comment: Oh, you mean too long for a comment? Just add it to the question

Comment: Ready, I got it !

Comment: Great! There seems to still be lots of missing dependencies, none of which seem relevant to the actual question. Can you remove those, so that the form gets displayed?

Comment: A try remove but the playground not show nothing

Comment: This kind of behavior is almost always because the parent element is not set to `position: relative`

Comment: Ok i try look the parent element ty for time